# th:text expression doesn't evaluate json string when json object key is of single character length

Tags: json, char, key, thymeleaf

We are using thymeleaf expressions to evaluate the json data.We pass the json string in context and parse this render it.
I have the following json passed in the context.

DESIGN_JSON= {title={name=My Test Title, label={Default=Title}, type=Textbox, autoGenerated=false, value=}, d={name=d, label={Default=Description}, type=Textbox, autoGenerated=false, value=}}

thymeleaf expressions:

Below expression Works fine and displays object {name=My Test Title, label={Default=Title}, type=Textbox, autoGenerated=false, value=}

```
<label name="t1" class="break-word" th:text="${DESIGN_JSON['title']}">title: </label>
```

But below expression doesn't work and displays blank

```
<label name="Desc" class="break-word" th:text="${DESIGN_JSON['d']}">Desc: </label>
```

Could any one help me on this regard?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please put your codes in a code section so that other recognize it better and have more readable content.  **add 4 four spaces (a tab) before each line of code, it will be showed to other as a code segment.**

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.